# Converting a five digit number to date format in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

In these spread sheets I have an entire column of values that are supposed to be dates, such as.

```
200701 = 1/1/2007
200702 = 2/1/2007
200905 = 5/1/2009
```

And so on and so forth.

These will all  be in column B (if that matters) and I was curious if there is a simple way to convert these into the desired date without doing a search and replace. Some of these spreadsheets are thousands upon thousands of pages long and it will be very time consuming.

Comment: Are there no digits for the month - ie: are they all month '1'?

Comment: Yeah, just having a "1" for the date is fine it seems, they are just more concerned with the month.

Comment: @Linker3000: The resulting dates are in `MM/DD/YYYY` form rather than `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula will extract the first four digits as the year, the second two as the month and use a 1 for the day. You can do a Paste Special Values, then delete the original original column if you only want the new result.

```
=DATE(MID(B1,1,4),MID(B1,5,2),1)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Anyway you could explain on why this works, out of my own curiosity?

Comment: The `DATE` formula takes `(YEAR,MONTH,DAY)` as arguments and converts them to a datetime value. The `MID` formula takes `(ADDRESS,START-CHAR,CHAR-COUNT)` as arguments so `(MID(B1,1,4)` says to extract four characters starting at the first and `MID(B1,5,2)` says to extract two starting at the fifth.

Comment: @AgainstClint: I forgot to prefix that comment with "@AgainstClint".

Comment: Also, just a weird heads up, if you put the data into a Pivot Table, it will convery the five digit number into the correct date and format.

Not exactly sure why that works, but it is kind of interesting.

Comment: @Dennis: Wondering why you have a preference for the Mid function as opposed to the Left and Right function in this particular case. Just curious. Thanks.

Comment: @Sux2Lose: They would work equally well, but I like the fact that the end of one (4) precedes the beginning of the next (5) for readability and that if you were also extracting the day-of-month you'd need to use `MID` for one field anyway.